# ggplot: multilayered x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am trying to make a box-whisker chart showing egg counts over time, dividing the year into dry and rainy seasons.  The chart below is almost there, but instead of continuing the month series, it re-starts the month names again for the rainy season.  It should be Nov-May, and then June-Oct.  What am I missing?

```
   ggplot(data=eggcounts3, mapping=aes(x=monthegg, y=Eggs, color=as.factor(monthegg)))+
      geom_boxplot(width=0.9)+
      ylim(0,12001)+
      xlab("Time of Year")+
      guides(color=FALSE)+
      ylab("Fecal Egg Count")+ 
      scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Nov","Dec","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct"))+
      facet_wrap(~NewSeason, strip.position = "bottom", scales = "free_x") +
      theme(strip.background = element_blank(),strip.placement = "outside",axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold"))
```

[image: Graph with wrong months]

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data using `dput`? You shouldn't need `scale_x_discrete`. Instead, make sure `monthegg` is a factor with the desired ordering. Before running the plot code, do `eggcounts3$monthegg = factor(eggcounts3$monthegg, levels=month.abb[c(11:12,1:10)])` (`month.abb` is a built-in vector). Then, in the plot, `facet_wrap(~NewSeason, strip.position = "bottom", scales = "free_x", space="free_x") +`

Comment: I did "glimpse" instead - I can't post the whole raw data here.  `glimpse(eggcounts3)
Observations: 788
Variables: 4
$ Eggs      <int> 3625, 50, 1425, 925, 2700, 50, 2875, 750, 2150, 0, 1125, 7500, ...
$ Season    <chr> "Spring", "Summer", "Summer", "Fall", "Fall", "Fall", "Winter",...
$ NewSeason <fctr> Rainy, Rainy, Rainy, Rainy, Rainy, Dry, Dry, Dry, Dry, Dry, Ra...
$ monthegg  <fctr> 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, ...
>levels(eggcounts3$monthegg)
 [1] "11" "12" "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"`

Comment: It complained about the space="free_x" so I removed that bit.  Now this produces a graph that is closer to what I want (the months are labeled correctly with numbers), but I was hoping to use month abbreviations for even easier communication (hence my scale_discrete_x line). Recoding the data from numerical to character/factor months seems easiest now.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: use `dput(eggcounts3)` to post structure of your data and also don't post it as comment. Edit your question and put it there.